# Which database is connected for sleeping connection in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a web application on .NET Framework 3.5. The database server is SQL Server 2008. In connectionStrings of web.config, the database name is set as “mydatabase”. Mini pool size is set to 50. 
When I use sp_who to check database connections, I found that for most of sleeping connection, the dbname is master, not “mydatabase”. My question is: is master the database for all sleeping connections, or is there some wrong about my configuration?

Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 1):

> > for most of sleeping connection, the dbname is master, not “mydatabase”.

In SQL Server, user sessions (spid or session_id) start from 51 and any sessions before 50 are system background processess. Master Database holds key information for most of these background processess and what you see is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Hi Sankar, thank you very much! Your confirmation is very helpful! :)